# How can I create a movie effect with a few images using jquery?

Tags: jquery, animation

I want 11 images to fade in and fade out in a sequence. I have stored them in an array and want to cycle through them one by one and display them inside a single div. But it only displays the last image in the array 11 times. Please point me in the right direction. Just starting with jquery.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // variable counter for image number. 
    slideNum = 1;
    $("#startComic").click(function() {
        var movie = [];
        while (slideNum <= 11) {
            movie[slideNum - 1] = '<img src="images/slide (' + slideNum + ').png"' + ' alt = "movie slide">';
            slideNum++;
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < movie.length; i++) {
            $("#slide").html(movie[i]);
            $("#slide").fadeIn(1000);
            $("#slide").fadeOut(2000);

        }
    });
});
```

And here is the html.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <title>Web Comic</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 <script src="../jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
 <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <button class="btn btn-primary" id="startComic">Start</button>
 <div id="slide"></div>
 <button class="btn btn-primary" id="playAgain">Play Again</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those fadeIn and fadeOut functions are asynchronous, they run concurrently which is why you only see the last image.

Assuming you've populated the array, try something like:

```
function nextImage(intImage) {
    // Bail after the last image.
    //
    if (intImage == movie.length)
        return;

    $("#slide").html(movie[intImage]);
    $("#slide").fadeIn(1000);
    $("#slide").fadeOut(1000);

    // recursively call this function with increased intImage
    // after a 2 second timeout to ensure both animations are complete
    //
    setTimeout(function() {
        nextImage(intImage + 1);
    }, 2000);
}
```

Something like this should work. Populate your array as before then simply call the function passing intImage as 0 to begin at image 0:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // variable counter for image number. 
    slideNum = 1;
    $("#startComic").click(function() {
        var movie = [];
        while (slideNum <= 11) {
            movie[slideNum - 1] = '<img src="images/slide (' + slideNum + ').png"' + ' alt = "movie slide">';
            slideNum++;
        }

        nextImage(0);
    });
});
```

Hope this helps, typed it up quick as I'm currently at work, skiving.

Comment: Thank you very much. it worked exactly as i wanted. There is a typo in the code here:  nextImage( intImage + ! ). I am not able to change it to 1. Kindly look at it.

Comment: Gracias for pointing that out, much appreciated and glad to help.